# Python Pandas Bar plot shows no color

Tags: python, pandas

When I follow the examples in the pandas documentation for visualizing a bar chart:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

See the first example titled `Basic plot.` with 3 bars.

The pandas documentation shows:
[image: pandas bar chart basic plot]

But when I type the same in my local jupyter notebook, I get no color:
[image: my jupyter notebook bar plot with no color]

Why does my notebook not have color?  What can I do to display the colors?

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?. This works for `pandas>=0.23`.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can pass custom colors to `df.plot`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"lab":["A","B","C"], "val":[10,20,30]})
df.plot.bar(x="lab", y="val", rot=0, color = ["y","c","m"])
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Here is a [LINK](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html) to the some more about the one-letter color abbreviations

Comment: also possible to write in more compact way `color='ycm'`